# Ember: ArrayController computed property based on array item properties

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayContoller on which I want to set a boolean property based on the properties of its contents.

Plain-language description of the logic:

If the array contains *any* items with a property of `isRetired` equal to `true`, set the `retiredShoes` property of the ArrayController to `true`, otherwise, set the ArrayController `retiredShoes` property to `false`.

It seems like this should be a simple matter, but I haven't found a solution anywhere, and I'm still pretty new at this.

I'll put together a jsfiddle if necessary.

Here are the controllers for the array and the object:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['title'],
    itemController: 'shoe',
    retiredShoes: function() {
        //how do I compute this sucker?
    }
});

App.ShoeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    actions: {
        delete: function() {
            var shoe = this.get('model'),
                runs = shoe.get('runs');
            shoe.deleteRecord();
            shoe.save();
        },
        toggleRetired: function() {
            var shoe = this.get('model');
            shoe.toggleProperty('isRetired');
            shoe.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off top of my head, without jsbin. If there's a problem/bug, drop me a comment and I'll look it over again.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    retiredShoes: function() {
        return this.get("model").isAny("isRetired", true);
    }.property("model.@each.isRetired")
});
```

Comment: The top of your head was exactly right. I KNEW it had to be simple. Many thanks, @panta82.